# How to pass number field value to star image in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

How to pass number field value to star image in visualforce page?.i am having test__c value = 3,i need to show these 3 values in star image.can anybody help me on this.

Comment: Just for confirmation, If the field have the value as 5, then 5 stars should be shown in the VF Page field. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes exactly,how to pass value to star image and value having 3 need to change colour of the star image as like 3 stars

Comment: Changing of colour means, Using Jquery will be a better solution...Try the Rikshit Rawat's Answer.....

Comment: I already tried that jquery.its not working. but i need to pass only one salesforce object one number field value only.

Comment: try this one http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2127319-adding-rating-stars-to-your-salesforce-lead-and-contact-layouts

Comment: Thanks for giving this link EDWARD. i used like this it showing stars and i saved the images and getting from static resource and i given access visual force page to site and i given user access permissions and field level security also but it showing broken image. how to view the image in sites.help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach you can try. I have used 5 different `divs` to show the rating based on the number value. The `div's` display style is decided based on the number. In this solution I have used html character `&#x2606;` to show the star instead of image. You can tweak the CSS as per your requirement. Hope this will help.

```
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" >
    <style type="text/css">
        .rating {
          font-size:24px;
        }        
    </style>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            Rating:
            <div class="rating" style="{!IF(Book__c.test__c==1, 'display:block;', 'display:none;')}">
                <span>&#x2606;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating" style="{!IF(Book__c.test__c==2, 'display:block;', 'display:none;')}">
                <span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating" style="{!IF(Book__c.test__c==3, 'display:block;', 'display:none;')}">
                <span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="rating" style="{!IF(Book__c.test__c==4, 'display:block;', 'display:none;')}">
                <span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span>
            </div>            
            <div class="rating" style="{!IF(Book__c.test__c==5, 'display:block;', 'display:none;')}">
                <span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span><span>&#x2606;</span>
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

[image]